# Sphinx avg function from PHP-api

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

I have this mysql table:

```
CREATE TABLE person (id INT(6) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,name    VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,age int(4) NOT NULL);
```

I run these inserts:
    INSERT INTO person VALUES(null, 'one', 42);
    INSERT INTO person VALUES(null, 'two', 49);
    INSERT INTO person VALUES(null, 'three', 16);

Running:

```
select avg(age) from person;
```

gives me "35.6"

I then index these table in Sphinx. Now I want to run more or less the same query in Sphinx as the one I run in MySQL.
From command line I issue this command:

```
select avg(age) from person_idx;
```

Fine. Even here I get "35.6".

Now to the problem. I need to run this query from PHP. Im using sphinxapi.php script that comes with Sphinx-release.
I had a look at the docs and googled a lot. But I cannot find a way to run these kind of functions (avg, sum etc) from PHP.
Is there a way to do this?

In PHP I have this code:

```
require('sphinxapi.php');
$client = new SphinxClient();
$res = $client->Query('', 'person_idx');
```

Where do I put the "select AVG(age)" part of the sql-query?
sphinxapi.php has a methods you can call. But I cannot see a way to decide what to select.

Comment: What do you mean run from php?You just run your  query using php libraries or spinx library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add before the Query() call

```
$client->setSelect("AVG(age) AS avg_age");
```

setSelect is roughly equivalent to the 'SELECT ...' part of sphinxQL. But in general you need to use `AS` for all function use.

Comment: I am using sphinxapi.php which is shipped with release of sphinx-server. The documentation is here: http://sphinxsearch.com/wiki/doku.php?id=php_api_docs I cannot se the function "setSelect". So I guess you are talking about sphix-api found here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.sphinx.php ? I would prefer to use the first one, as its the one Im using right now for all the application. But question is if there is something equivalent in that API.

Comment: Hmm, that documentation is WAY old "It is current as of Sphinx 0.9.8-r1065." are you really using such a old version of sphinx???? (you cant be because it doesnt have sphinxql!) The offical documentation is here: http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/ (choose your version)